# How to set properly aligned KPIs for engineers and QA staff

Tags: quality, quality-management, performance, reviews, kpi

## Intro

I like to setup KPIs for my engineering/QA teams. I use that to evaluate performance and help determine bonus/raise each quarter.

This is one KPI I set for my engineers:

- % of tasks that passed QA with no bugs

  - ie depending on the QA flow (per issue or per sprint), we see how many bugs were reported against all the issues that were completed by 1. the engineer that fixed the issue 2. the other engineer that peer reviewed it.

    - ie in a given sprint engineer X resolved 20 issues, which got reviewed by engineer Y. Assuming the QA does their work on a sprint basis, and that the QA found 5 bugs in those 20 issues, the tasks that passed QA with no bugs percentage is 75%
- % of tasks that functioned properly post deployment 
  Same idea as above, but this one will be treated for code that actually gets released live and is used by users

This is one KPI I have for my QA staff:

- number of bugs found per issue

  - ie the more bugs a QA person finds in an issue the better.

## Problem

The KPIs for the engineers and QA personnel seem contradictory, or said another way: they seem like a zero sum game. Which obviously isn't good for employee morale and would cause rivalry/resentment.

How can I change this so that both engineers and QA staff have KPIs that make them work together as opposed to against each other?

---

## update: a concrete case

this is in response to [novigt](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/7559/nvoigt)'s [answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/20767/23022) below as well as in reference to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285097/is-it-good-that-testers-are-competing-to-see-who-opens-more-bugs#comment587168_285097) comment on a related post:

> Are the testers involved before a build? Meaning are they involved in
>   developing the requirements or use cases or user stories, reviewing
>   design documentation, or participating in code reviews?..

I figured that proper and sound documentation of scenarios is a huge part of evaluating QA personnel (keep in mind here I'm talking about non-technical QA who simply do black box testing and cannot do automated tests etc).

I agree that a metric that calculates total number of bugs is bogus, and i agree with the **incidents in production** metric.

Let me explain my new metric with an example:

[image]

Suppose I have a single login screen (forgot password/remember me etc not included for brevity) that I would like to build and deploy. Using [Gherkin Syntax](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) the QA engineer writes the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Happy path login**
`given` user enters correct username/pwd
`when` user clicks on login
`then` user should be directed to dashboard

**Scenario 2: login failure**
`given` user enters false username/pwd
`when` user clicks on login
`then` error message shows: *incorrect username/pwd*

this documentation is given to the engineers (along with the designs) on **sprint one** , who develop it, peer review it, send it back to QA for testing and then is deployed in version **0.0.01** of the app.

Once on prod, the following bug happens

`given` user enters correct username/pwd
`and` the server is down
`when` user clicks on login
`then`
**expected**
user should get an error message: *service is currently unavailable*
**actual**
a spinner spins for ever

---

Here are the KPIs/metrics we capture for this scenario:

- number of scenarios: **2**
- number of incidents in production: **1**

---

metrics as a snapshot don't give the whole picture, so let's go on:

so on **sprint two**, the QA staff updates the documentation with scenario 3:

**scenario 3: handle login when server is down**
`given` user enters correct username/pwd
`and` the server is down
`when` user clicks on login
`then` user should get an error message: *service is currently unavailable*

the engineers fix that bug, and deploy it on release **0.0.02**, on the release this bug happens:

`given` user enters correct username/pwd
`and` the user is not connected to the internet
`when` user clicks on login
`then`
**expected**
user should get an error message: *user is offline*
**actual**
a spinner spins for ever

---

Here are the KPIs/metrics we capture for this scenario:

- number of scenarios: **3**
- number of incidents in production: **1**
- rate of increase of scenarios: 33%
- rate of decrease of incidents in production: 0%

---

so we use the last two KPIs (increase in scenarios and decrease of incidents in production) together to evaluate the performance of a QA person. The final evaluation should use both KPIs (in addition to other metrics that can be discussed elsewhere) to evaluate an engineer. This way increasing useless case scenarios alone won't be positive alone, and also an increase in incidents in production without a corresponding increase in scenarios should be a red flag for the engineer. I know one can also achieve this by having comprehensive unit tests that have >95% code coverage etc.. but let's assume we're not there yet.

Is there a problem with this?

Comment: "Once on prod, the following bug happens" This is **not a bug**. A bug is a deviation from the spec. This was never in the spec to start with. Labelling this as a bug will make your Engineers *very* unhappy. A bug is a mistake I made as an Engineer, something not working to spec. Something not in the spec is a *feature request* and should never be held against anybody but the one writing specs.

Comment: @nvoigt fair enough i won't call it a bug, i'll call it **spec miss**.. and so a KPI for QA staff (again, _not_ engineers) is the amount of spec misses per sprint.. works?

Comment: Who makes the judgement that the QA *should* have specced that? And if that person knows what should have been specced, why didn't s/he do it in the first place instead of letting the poor QA guys guess?

Comment: It's the QA's job to ensure that documentation covers all possible user cases. This doesn't mean that all those use cases will be implemented in release 0.0.01, but we at least need to know they exist (they can be done in a later release as per the lean model). 

Further this isn't an all or nothing. I'm not saying that if a **spec miss** happens the QA will get beat up in the parking lot. I'm saying that these are metrics we can use as a supplement in their evaluation...

Comment: .. Ie when I evaluate an employee I look at several things, including their KPI's. You are making an absolute statement that all metrics/KPI's are bad? 

Let me try to see things more from your perspective. Assuming that you have knowledge workers reporting to you, how do _you_ evaluate their performance (with the absence of any metric)? And how can you back up that evaluation? How can you scale that process?

Comment: Well, if your QA writes your specs, I hope you pay them damn well, because that's well above the pay grade of normal QA work. It would be the job of a business analyst or product owner, depending on how agile you want to be. Anyway, no I don't have KPIs and I can only judge based on my understanding of the technical part plus my gut feeling. I'm not saying that's great. It just beats the metrics I've seen so far. I would love to have transparent KPIs, but all I know can be gamed easily by knowledge workers. In the end, it's delivery of a bug-free product that counts.

Comment: .. but we know a bug-free product doesn't exist in real life?

Comment: anyways.. you already gave me so much food for thought.. i gotta read some books and do some more research, i definitely don't feel as strongly about all of this as I did.. thanks for all your info :)

Comment: You're welcome. I like the fact that you think about it. There are too many people out there who don't (and I've seen *their* metrics...).

Comment: Quick question @nvoigt: what do you think of the idea of using metrics to improve processes in the organization rather than punishment/reward of individuals ? Ie data driven process improvement

Answer (score 4):

So right now, as an Engineer, I take a single task, mull over it for 4 weeks, make sure it contains no bugs at all and I am the best worker you ever had. Despite the fact that it took me 4 weeks to deliver such a simple task.

On the other hand, you have QA, who is wildly dependent on getting a crappy Engineer assigned. The crappier the engineer, the more rewards the QA will get. What happens if I have to test a product from a good Engineer? Will I be put on a performance improvement plan for not finding enough bugs?

Your metrics are arbitrary and less than useful. Your people are not worker drones, they use their intelligence to get their job done. So don't insult them with metrics that can easily be gamed.

At least start with what really matters: **incidents in production**. Bugs that escaped both Engineers *and* QA. Try to minimize those and you will see that Engineers and QA are actually a team working towards the same end goal.

However, it's debatable whether having metrics is worth it for intelligence workers. Nobody has found the right ones yet and the wrong ones can backfire easily. If you base anything on your KPIs (like praise or salary) be prepared that people will be clever enough to outsmart you on any of them. Then you are stuck with people that did their jobs, but look average on the metrics and people that gamed the system instead of doing a good job, but look great on your system.

Comment: Your point is well taken about the initial kpi being not useful, I updated my question with a different metric that hopefully addresses your points. Please take a look.

Also: _it's debatable whether having metrics is worth it for intelligence workers. Nobody has found the right ones yet_ can you please mention a research or statistic (or even some opinion piece) that supports that point?

Comment: @abbood No I cannot back something up that does not exist. I have never seen KPIs that worked well for knowledge workers, nor heard from them. If you find some, let me know, I'd be happy to have them.

Comment: @abbood Joel has (had, but I'm not aware of changes) a [similar outlook on KPIs for knowledge workers](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/07/15/20020715/).

Comment: @nvoigt How does BA evaluate the solution using KPI? Actually I have few recommendations on business operational and technological aspects and trying to evaluate the solution but I am really having a hard time identifying the KPI. Can you give me at least 2-3 KPI for that to kick start or give me an idea how the KPI should be please